# Realm data is saved to database but is not populating labels in Swift 4

Tags: ios, realm, swift4

I am making an app that uses Realm to persist data, and I have run into a small bug and cant seem to figure it out. I know it has to be something simple that I am overlooking, as I have a couple other View Controllers that use very similar code and they work. so here it is.

I have a View Controller that has inputs for information and it works fine sends the data to Realm. On a different View Controller I have code to display that data in labels but it does not display the information on the labels they are blank in fact even the default text does not show on the screen? Help!!!

Here is the code for the display VC.

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class CompanyViewController: UIViewController {

    var myCompany: Results<CompanyInfo>?

    let realm = try! Realm()

    var selectedCompany: CompanyInfo? {
        didSet { }
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        loadCompany()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        nameLabel?.text = selectedCompany?.companyName
        addressLabel.text = selectedCompany?.companyAddress
        cityLabel.text = selectedCompany?.companyCity
        stateLabel.text = selectedCompany?.companyState
        postalLabel.text = selectedCompany?.companyPostalCode
        phoneLabel.text = selectedCompany?.companyPhoneNumber
        emailLabel.text = selectedCompany?.companyEmail
    }

    func loadCompany(){
        myCompany = realm.objects(CompanyInfo.self)
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var addressLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var cityLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var stateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var postalLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var phoneLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailLabel: UILabel!

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "AddCompanySegue" {
            guard segue.destination is UINavigationController else { return }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share the declaration of your `CompanyInfo` class.

Comment: Where are you giving any value to `selectedCompany`? `selectedCompany` is nil and that is why your labels are getting without value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `loadCompany` method before set the labels text values, something like this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //first load the company
        self.loadCompany()

        nameLabel?.text = selectedCompany?.companyName
        addressLabel.text = selectedCompany?.companyAddress
        cityLabel.text = selectedCompany?.companyCity
        stateLabel.text = selectedCompany?.companyState
        postalLabel.text = selectedCompany?.companyPostalCode
        phoneLabel.text = selectedCompany?.companyPhoneNumber
        emailLabel.text = selectedCompany?.companyEmail
    }
```

other issue is what is selectedCompany? assuming that is the first result of your `realm` query, your `loadCompany` method should be something like this

```
  func loadCompany(){
        myCompany = realm.objects(CompanyInfo.self)
        if(myCompany.count > 0){
        //Asigning value to "selectedCompany" variable
        self.selectedCompany = myCompany[0]
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you I got it to work using your response with one minor change to the loadCompany. I am not sure if != (not equal) operates in this case as > but the code now populates the labels.                                                                                         func loadCompany(){
        myCompany = realm.objects(CompanyInfo.self)
        if(myCompany?.count  != 0){
            //Asigning value to "selectedCompany" variable
            self.selectedCompany = myCompany?[0]
        }
    }